# Laravel: Multi observer

Tags: database, laravel, observers

In my project, the "non-connector" tables have six log columns at the end of the table:

`created_at`, `create_user_id`, `updated_at`, `update_user_id`, `deleted_at`, `delete_user_id`.

I now update the `*_user_id` cells with Observers, but my project is a growing project and in X years it can be Y tables like this, that means I have Y observers and Y rows at the ServiceProvider.

Is there any universal methods for handling these or an observer what observes all of these tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just create a trait and use it in any model you want to keep track with

```
 trait Trackable
{
    public static function bootTrackable()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            // blah blah
        });

        static::updating(function ($model) {
            // bleh bleh
        });

        static::deleting(function ($model) {
            // bluh bluh
        });
    }
}

MyModel extends Model {
    use Trackable;

    // etc...
}
```